# Integration the bank payment system

Tags: python, django, python-requests, rsa, payment

I am trying to integrate the Bank's payment system on my Django-based website. As it said in documentation, I need to send parameters to their server (and then the new window should appear and the client should fill his card credentials there).

Documentation (part 1): [image]

Documentation (part 2):
[image]

Documentation (part 3):
[image]

I am new in integration such services (payment) and need some help or broad explanation what to do, why do to that, and how.

Additionally, I was pretty sure that the following code wouldn't work fine but why.

```
import requests


def send_request():
    url = 'https://ecomm.pashabank.az:18443/ecomm2/MerchantHandler/?command=v&amount=5&currency=932&client_ip_addr=167.184.1.132&msg_type=SMS'
    response = requests.post(url)
    print(response)

send_request()
```

causes

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ecomm.pashabank.az', port=18443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ecomm2/MerchantHandler/?command=v&amount=5&currency=932&client_ip_addr=167.172.184.123&msg_type=SMS (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Overall, I need help of everything happening behind the scenes. Huge thanks in advance guys!

Note: I have also received some certifications from bank (I assume to assure the connection safety). But how I use it and when?

Comment: why this question got -1 vote without any edition and comments?

Comment: The error is that the bank self-signed their certificates. That's extremely fishy. Are you sure you have the correct URL that matches a real bank?

Comment: yup bro. i got those certificates from bank and everything is fine about safety, but the problem is i dont get the general concept of integration such kind of systems (payment in our case). i dont know whether i am sending the whole request (url with parameters) correctly

Comment: No you have a certificate error, the request is never sent, since python will throw a error for a invalid certificate while establishing the connection

Comment: Bro, how can python knows about the certificate itself? I dont even attach any certs in my request and in the code. I only have them in some folder and thats all. I am asking what are the certs and how to use them (maybe attach, as i said earlier, or do whatever). I am pretty sure those certificate are valid as I have received them from the official Bank. The question is what is next

Comment: Read up on how SSL certificates and HTTP work

Comment: it will give me the answer?